# Remove NaN value, javascript

Tags: javascript, nan

Index 28:

[image]

How do I remove this "NaN" value. Cant use `isNaN` because I want strings and numbers. But not NaN

Tried:

```
typeof value === 'undefined'
value == null
```

No success.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test for `NaN` specifically by using [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN), which is subtly different from plain `isNaN`: It only returns true if its argument is a number (whose value is NaN). In other words, it won't try to coerce strings and other values to numbers.

Demo:

```js
const values = [
  12,
  NaN,
  "hello",
  { foo: "bar" },
  NaN,
  null,
  undefined,
  -3.14,
];

const filtered = values.filter(x => !Number.isNaN(x));

console.log(filtered);
```

`Number.isNaN` is new in ECMAScript 6. It is supported by every browser except Internet Explorer. In case you need to support IE, here's a simple workaround:

```
if (!Number.isNaN) {
    Number.isNaN = function (x) { return x !== x; };
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's new to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `typeof` (to check that's a number) in combination with `isNaN`

Note that `typeof NaN` returns `"number"`

```
typeof x === "number" && isNaN(x)
```

Another solution is to use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) which will not trying to convert the parameter into a number. So it will return `true` only when the parameter is `NaN`

Comment: Put `typeof` first, so it doesn't waste time trying to parse things that aren't numbers.

Comment: I know that sounds like a micro-optimization, but it also expressed the logic better.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [Number.isNaN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN)

```js
console.log([1, "foo", NaN, "bar"].filter((x) => !Number.isNaN(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I’ve seen this comparison check, not sure if you could make it work for you.

```
var nanValue = NaN;
if(nanValue !== nanValue) // Returns true!
    alert('nanValue is NaN');
```